# Angular Firestore: What is the correct syntax for a collection query that uses a where clause?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have working code that queries Firestore and returns an Observable of type `ImageUploadWId[]`. I would like to return a `Promise` instead. This is because

1. my data isn't changing often;
2. I am performing deletes based on the data that comes in.

`SnapshotChanges()` returns an array of actions. The first action contains an incomplete array of size 1. The last action contains an array of size 4. The last array is complete; it has all the `ImageUploadWIds` from the one `groupId`.

I want just one array that has the `ImageUploadWIds` from only the designated groupId. Using a Promise is giving me the `ImageUploadWIds` from all the `groupIds`. I believe the where clause isn't working.

Here is my working code, which only prints `imageUpload`groupIds from one groupId, but returns more than one array. The last array is the only one I need. Edit (added log statements):

```
getImageInfosWIds(bathroomGroupId: string): Observable<ImageUploadWId[]> {
  return this.afs.collection(this.bathroomImagesLocation,
    ref => ref.where('groupId', '==', bathroomGroupId)).snapshotChanges()
    .map(actions => {
      return actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data();
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        const imageUpload = new ImageUploadWId();
        imageUpload.set(id, <ImageUpload>data);
        return imageUpload;
      })
    })
}

onDeleteGroup(groupId: string) {
this.bathroomGroupService.getImageInfosWIds(groupId)
  .subscribe((imageUploads) => {
    console.log("imageUploads.length: " + imageUploads.length);
    for (let imageUpload of imageUploads) {
      console.log("(groupId, filename): (" + imageUpload.groupId + ", " + imageUpload.filename + ")");
    }
  })
}
```

Here is my code trying to use a Promise. This prints imageUploads from both of my groups instead of only from the given bathroomGroupId.

```
getImageInfosWIds(bathroomGroupId: string): Promise<QuerySnapshot> {
  return this.afs.collection(this.bathroomImagesLocation,
    ref => ref.where("groupId", "==", bathroomGroupId))
    .ref
    .get();
}

onDeleteGroup(groupId: string) {
  this.bathroomGroupService.getImageInfosWIds(groupId)
  .then( (querySnapshot) => {
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log("edit-bathrooms: " + doc.data().groupId);
      })
  },
  () => {console.log("Error in edit-bathrooms. promise unfullfilled " +
      "in onDeleteGroup( " + groupId + " )")});
}
```

Edit: This is the final code that worked:

```
  onDeleteGroup(groupId: string) {
    this.bathroomGroupService.getImageInfosWIdsObservable(groupId)
    .pipe(take(1)).subscribe(
    data => {
      console.log(data[0].groupId);
    });
  }

 getImageInfosWIdsObservable(bathroomGroupId: string) {
   return this.afs.collection(this.bathroomImagesLocation,
   ref => ref.where('groupId', '==', bathroomGroupId)).snapshotChanges() //rxjs 5 -> 6  library
   .pipe(
    map(actions => actions.map(a => {
      const data = a.payload.doc.data();
      const documentId = a.payload.doc.id;
      const imageUpload = new ImageUploadWId();
      imageUpload.set(documentId, <ImageUpload>data);
      return imageUpload;
    }))
  );
}
```

Just one final word. If you're still getting an extra array, you may have subscribed to the same Firestore collection in another part of your code and not unsubscribed. That was part of my problem.

Comment: your question title is deferent from details, i think! 
I cant understand (if u want the query syntax for where); or u want to change ur code to a Promise?

Comment: Hi Mohammad, I would like to have a promise that provides an array of ImageUploadWIds corresponding to the one groupId. The promise I have does not work. I believe it is because of the query that it doesn't work. If I can't have a promise, I'd be alright with an observable, but the code I have for the observable doesn't give me what I need. It gives me many arrays, the last array has the complete list of ImageUploadsWIds corresponding to the one groupId. The last array is what I need.

Comment: Try to return as list, since snapshotChanges() keep listen to the changes and load data in async.

Comment: Hi Rahul! This is the sequence of events. I upload 4 ImageUploads. Then I call 'getImageInfos()'. For some reason, I get one array with 1 ImageUpload and then an array with 4 ImageUploads. Is it returning a history of the changes in the database? How would I return a list? How would I know which array is the right one to turn into a list? As a workaround, I'm adding the ImageUploads to a Set so I don't have duplicates (that's not in the code). Do you think that Firebase is misbehaving? It should just give the existing 4 element array, and then if there are changes give another array, right?

Comment: Hi again Rahul. I think my most important question at this point is: Given the sequence of events, it should just give the existing 4 element array, and then if there are changes give another array, right?

Answer (score 2):

AngularFire2 wraps the Firebase reference, so calling `.ref.get()` creates a new reference and ignores the query function you supplied.

Luckily, RxJS makes it easy to convert an Observable to a Promise. You just need to pipe in `first()` or `take(1)` to force the Observable to complete (otherwise the promise will never resolve because Firebase provides an endless realtime stream).

```
 return this.afs.collection(...)
  .valueChanges()
  .pipe(first())
  .toPromise()
```

Comment: That's odd, you get an array with 1 object? it should emit all four as an array if the groupId is consistent and they live in the same collection.

Comment: Okay so the final code is in the last edit, using JeffD23's idea.

Comment: I believe my main problem was that I was not unsubscribing.

Answer (score 0):

It should be,

```
return this._afs.collection(this.bathroomImagesLocation, x => x
            .where('groupId', '==',bathroomGroupId));
```

Comment: I used your code except that I added .ref.get(); to the end to get a Promise and I have the same results. I have ImageUploadsWIds from both groups instead of just one. Excuse me if I'm wrong, but I think your code is the same as mine, except that you're using 'x' when I am using 'ref' for the query.