# Firebase Firestore how to query on a sub-colelction

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Here is my problem: i had to add a members to a sub-collection and query on them (Firebase Firestore don't provide any method to query on an array (array-contains isn't available for angular).

I tried to create a sub-collection who contains all my members (1 members = 1 doc of the sub-collection). How can I query this sub-collection to look at the name of the document ?

Thank you,
Hokijo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular Firestore: What is the correct syntax for a collection query that uses a where clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50381873/angular-firestore-what-is-the-correct-syntax-for-a-collection-query-that-uses-a)

Comment: It's a good idea to include your Firebase structure and what you've tried in questions. Please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)